# How to Convert .csv file to RDD<Vector>?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I have a CSV file containing following data with 9000+ records

```
 id,Category1,Category2
```

How do I convert this csv file to `RDD<Vector>` so that I can use it to find similar column using `columnSimilarities` of Apache Spark in java.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html#RowMatrix-org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sparkSession.read.csv(myCsvFilePath) // you should have a DataFrame here
  .map((r: Row) => Vector.dense(r.getInt(0), r.getInt(1), r.getInt(2))) // you should have a Dataset of Vector
  .rdd // you have your RDD[Vector]
```

Feel free to reach out if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Category1 and Category2 are of String type.Is there a way to convert it in RDD<Vector> format

Comment: @JitendraPatil you can associate an integer to each category or you can hash the categories if you have too much categories (hashing should allow you to have a very large number of categories with almost no collisions - ie two categories being hashed inadvertently to the same integer). Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

as I read, Vector can hold the ID and and double[] for the values.
you need to fill the Vector.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myfile.csv"), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

then you can iterate over lines, create a Vector for each line, fill it with the values (you need to parse them) and add them to the RDD